# Flutter Bloc Provider Error: Cannot Find The Correct Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am attempting to make an app and I wanted to use a Bloc provider to store a user's data when they create their account. I have the Firebase collection created with the fields already defined; however, when I attempt to run it in Flutter, I get a huge error. It essentially says that it cannot find the correct provider form my bloc. I'm not sure how to fix this error, so I would really appreciate some guidance :). I have attached a screenshot of the emulator screen with the error and possible reasons for the error, as well as my code:

[image]

Onboarding bloc code:

```
part 'onboarding_event.dart';
part 'onboarding_state.dart';

class OnboardingBloc extends Bloc<OnboardingEvent, OnboardingState> {
  final DatabaseRepository _databaseRepository;
  final StorageRepository _storageRepository;

  OnboardingBloc({
    required DatabaseRepository databaseRepository,
    required StorageRepository storageRepository,
  }) : 
  _databaseRepository = databaseRepository,
  _storageRepository = storageRepository,
  super(OnboardingLoading()) {
    on<StartOnboarding>(_onStartOnboarding);
    on<UpdateUser>(_onUpdateUser);
    on<UpdateUserImage>(_onUpdateUserImage);
  }

  Future<void> _onStartOnboarding(
    StartOnboarding event, 
    Emitter<OnboardingState> emit) 
    async {
      User user = User(
        id: '',
        name: '',
        birthdate: '',
        imageUrls: [],
        Goals: '',
        Interests: [],
        Focus: []);
        String documentId = await _databaseRepository.createUser(user);
        emit(OnboardingLoaded(user: user.copyWith(id: documentId)));
    }

  void _onUpdateUser(
    UpdateUser event, 
    Emitter<OnboardingState> emit) {
      if (state is OnboardingLoaded) {
        _databaseRepository.UpdateUser(event.user);
        emit(OnboardingLoaded(user: event.user));
      }
    }

  void _onUpdateUserImage(
    UpdateUserImage event, 
    Emitter<OnboardingState> emit) 
    async{
      if (state is OnboardingLoaded) {
        User user = (state as OnboardingLoaded).user;

        await _storageRepository.uploadImage(user, event.image);

        _databaseRepository.getUser(user.id!).listen((user) {
          add(UpdateUser(user: user));
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Account Onboarding Screen (where I mention the specific bloc):

```
class AccountOnboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountOnboarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String routeName = '/profile onboarding';

  static Route route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: routeName),
      builder: (context) => MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [BlocProvider<OnboardingBloc>(
          create: (_) => OnboardingBloc(
            databaseRepository: DatabaseRepository(), 
            storageRepository: StorageRepository())
            ..add(StartOnboarding()),
        )], 
        child: const AccountOnboarding()));
  }

  @override
  State<AccountOnboarding> createState() => _AccountOnboardingState();
  
}

class _AccountOnboardingState extends State<AccountOnboarding> {

    static const List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'Name'),
    Tab(text: 'Age and Profile'),
    Tab(text: 'Bio and Interests'),
    Tab(text: 'Selection')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
       child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        final TabController tabController = DefaultTabController.of(context)!;
        tabController.addListener(() {
          if (!tabController.indexIsChanging) {}
        });

    return BlocBuilder<OnboardingBloc, OnboardingState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is OnboardingLoading) {
          return
          const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (state is OnboardingLoaded) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff31708c),
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/Logo_Strength.png',
                  height: 50),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                  fontSize: 30),
                                  children: <TextSpan> [
                                    TextSpan(text: 'Stren', 
                                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                      color: Colors.white, 
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                                      letterSpacing: 1,
                                      shadows: [
                                        Shadow(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                          offset: const Offset(1.5, 0.0))
                                      ])),
                
                                    TextSpan(text: ';', 
                                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                      color: const Color(0xffef6a7a), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                                      letterSpacing: 1,
                                      shadows: [
                                        Shadow(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                          offset: const Offset(1.5, 0.0))
                                      ])),
                
                                    TextSpan(text: 'th', 
                                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                      color: Colors.white, 
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                                      letterSpacing: 1,
                                      shadows: [
                                        Shadow(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                          offset: const Offset(1.5, 0.0))
                                      ]))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            NamePage(tabController: tabController,),
            ageAndPicture(tabController: tabController,),
            bioAndInterests(tabController: tabController,),
            SelectionPage(tabController: tabController,)
          ],
        ),
        );
      }
      else {return
        const Text('Something went wrong.');
      }
      }
    );
    
  }));
}}
```

Main dart:

```
int? isViewed;
Future <void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
  
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final showLogin = prefs.getBool('showLogin') ?? false;
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  
// This is for our onboarding screen
isViewed = prefs.getInt('onboard');

  runApp(MyApp(showLogin: showLogin));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showLogin;
  
  const MyApp({Key? key,
  required this.showLogin}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Strength',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      
      home: AccountOnboarding() // FINAL SCREEN IS SPLASH SCREEN
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your MaterialApp

Comment: This error indicates that you did not initialize your block with provider, usually this is done in MaterialApp, WidgetApp or when loading a screen. Note this [example here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/flutter_bloc/example/lib/main.dart), on line 36 you have a BlocProvider.

Comment: Use `BlocProvider` or `MultiBlocProvider` on `home` or over `MaterialApp` based on your need

Comment: @Chance I see. My problem then is trying to initialize the bloc without changing any page routes. All I see it it being done in the main dart, but I don't wan't to change my initial screen or the flow of my screens (like the answer provided below)

Comment: But somehow you need to add the bloc to the screen's context, and that's the role of the provider, but it can be done in several ways, like navigating the routes property of MaterialApp. I also don't understand what you mean by changing my home screen. The provider just injects the block into the context.

Comment: @Chance As I mentioned, if I do it in my main dart (like most examples do) I will have to set my home page to be the bloc provider. My bloc provider is not used until 4-5 screens in, so I'm not sure how to set it up in my main dart file without setting it as my original screen when the app launches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add provider on main.dart. It can be on Material `home:`

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => OnboardingBloc ()
            ),
        ),
      ],
      child: const AccountOnboarding(), 
    );
  }
```

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showLogin;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.showLogin}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Strength',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MultiBlocProvider(
        child: AccountOnboarding(),
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => OnboardingBloc(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [flutter bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts)

Comment: I see what you mean. My question then is does this change my home page when I launch the app? My first screen will always be my splash screen, but I am working out some kinks with my onboarding screen, hence why it is shown as my home screen for the time being. If I set my home as the MultiBlocProvider, will it not immediately launch the app to go directly to that screen?

Comment: Yes it will, think about MultiBlocProvider as a wrapper and its child as Home widget.  While navigating different route use `BlocProvider.value(`. You can check the doc for more

Comment: I've read all of the documentation and watched several videos on Bloc providers, but it's a concept that's still unclear to me so I don't understand how blocprovider.value will help (the documentation is not very detailed)

Comment: Hello, so I've updated to code (Onboarding dart), and I still run into the same error. I thought I added the provider correctly and double checked it too, but the error doesn't change at all

Comment: Use `MultiBlocProvider` as I've included on home and when you are navigating to a new route , follow `Navigator.of(context).push(  MaterialPageRoute(  builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(value: BlocProvider.of<OnboardingBloc>(context),child:YourNewWidget`